# How do i get input form value without submitting it?

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want the input value from user without submitting any thing then i want to pass it through ajax method as parameter to action method. I tried many method but i could not found a solution.

Here is the code

```html
<input type="text" id="task" name="task" value="" />


              @Ajax.ActionLink("ADD TASK", "show_task",new {task=Request["task"]}, new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "print",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

})
```

Here is the controller action method

```js
  public ActionResult show_task(string task)
        {
            var add_task = new tasks_table();
            add_task.task = task;
            add_task.id = 24;
           add_task.f_id=10;
            add_task.date_oftask=DateTime.Now;

            db.tasks_table.Add(add_task);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var tasks = db.tasks_table.Include(t => t.user_detail);
            return PartialView("render_tasks",tasks);                  

        }
```

Comment: **I want the input value from user**  when you want it ? You should know your requirements .

Comment: when user enter his value then after clicking on ajax method i want that value to pass with ajax method as action method's parameter

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the current value of the textbox, you may better do it yourself with your own javascript code to make the ajax call, instead of relying on the `Ajax.ActionLink` helper method.

So change your Ajax.ActionLink call to a normal action link.

```
<input type="text" id="task" name="task" value="" />
@Html.ActionLink("Add Task","show_task", null, new {id="addTask"})
<div id="print"></div>
```

Now listen to the `click` event on this link, read the value of the text box and send that to your server. You may use jQuery `$.post` method to do so. In the response callback, you can update the print div's content with the response coming  back from your server.

```
$(function(){

   $("a#addTask").click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();
     $.post($(this).attr("href"), { task:$("#task").val()},function(res){
        $("#print").html(res);
     });

   });

});
```

Comment: I follow your instructions and i did same thing as you mentioned  but when i clicked on link nothing is happening . It is not clicking.

Comment: What you mean it is not clicking ? do you have any js errors ? Open your browser console and see whether it is making a server call (or any errors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `focusOut` function to send the value to controller.
by `focusOut` method, we get the value in input field instantly when we moved to next field.

```
  $('#task').focusOut(function(){
    Your ajax call method....
 });
```

Hopes it helps.